# How can I query a date range for .msg emails using Azure AI Search?

Tags: azure, azure-ai-search

How can I query email created date for a range of dates in my Azure AI Search queries?  I can't seem to find samples for either of the query JSONs below:

{
"queryType": "full",
"search": "metadata_creation_date:???",
"searchMode": "all"
}

{
"search": "{{search}}",
"select": "metadata_creation_date",
"searchFields": "metadata_subject",
"count": true
}

Comment: One thing to note; the metadata_creation_date is a string so it will probably need to be parsed into a DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can query JSON to retrieve .msg emails within a specified date range.

[image]

```json
{
    "search": "*",
    "filter": "DateSent ge 'start_date' and DateSent le 'end_date'",
    "select": "From, To, CC, BCC, DateSent, Subject, Body"
}
```

```json
{

"search": "*",

"filter": "DateSent ge '2023-01-01T08:00:00Z' and DateSent le '2023-01-02T08:00:00Z'",

"select": "From, To, CC, BCC, DateSent, Subject, Body"

}
```

[image]

I added indexing like this.

```json
{
    "name": "email-index",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "MessageId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false},
        {"name": "From", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
        {"name": "To", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "facetable": true},
        {"name": "CC", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "facetable": true},
        {"name": "BCC", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "facetable": true},
        {"name": "DateSent", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true},
        {"name": "Subject", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
        {"name": "Body", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true}
    ]
}
```

I sent a sample data using this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/search-documents-readme?view=azure-python).

```json
{
        "MessageId": "1",
        "From": "sender@example.com",
        "To": ["recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com"],
        "CC": ["cc1@example.com", "cc2@example.com"],
        "BCC": ["bcc1@example.com", "bcc2@example.com"],
        "DateSent": "2023-01-01T08:00:00Z",
        "Subject": "Sample email 1",
        "Body": "This is the body of sample email 1."
    },
    {
        "MessageId": "2",
        "From": "sender@example.com",
        "To": ["recipient3@example.com"],
        "CC": ["cc3@example.com"],
        "BCC": [],
        "DateSent": "2023-01-02T08:00:00Z",
        "Subject": "Sample email 2",
        "Body": "This is the body of sample email 2."
    },
    {
        "MessageId": "3",
        "From": "another_sender@example.com",
        "To": ["recipient4@example.com"],
        "CC": [],
        "BCC": [],
        "DateSent": "2023-01-03T08:00:00Z",
        "Subject": "Sample email 3",
        "Body": "This is the body of sample email 3."
    }
```

[image]